# How to work with data from excelfile that is crerated by another programm

Tags: excel, vb.net-2010

How can I save an instance of excel (with vb.net) that is opened by another programm.

example; I am making an export to an exelfile from pragram A. Programm A export the  data to Book1.xlsx. At this moment i want to start working with this data with Program B

If I open an excelfile with a code in vb.net (xlWorkBook1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\DataBaseexcel\oprp_Choc.xlsm", Password:="password") I know how to do this, but not if the file is already opened by another programm and never saved on a drive.

Hope This will be clear enough